# How to use cronjob to execute CodeIgniter function of sending mail on siteground?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, cpanel

I want to use cron job to send email everyday 9AM. For that I have written one function named `send_email` in User controller. How to write a command to execute my function at 9AM everyday using cronjob which is hosted on siteground?

Comment: where you have hosted site? godaddy or what?

Comment: we have hosted site on siteground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NOTE:Go to cronjob section of your hosting provider and write down as
>   below:

**Your command:**

```
0 9 0 0 0 wget https://www.test.com/myfunction
```

**Syntxt for cron job:**

```
minutes (0 to 59)
hours (0 to 23)
day of month (1 to 31)
month (1 to 12)
day of week (0 – 6)
command (command to be executed)
```

Comment: "php /home/<CPANEL USERNAME>/public_html/<project folder>/index.php User send_email" is this command wrong?

Comment: @PraddyumnaSangvikar post your function path with controller in the question, so that I can write what you have to do.

Comment: It is done then accept so that other users can get it! @PraddyumnaSangvikar

Comment: @PraddyumnaSangvikar glad to help you!

Comment: @PathikVejani this gives me "json parse failed" on cpanel

Comment: @Terix it will be in your code error. check your function you have created.